# tailwind@1.9.6 how to use extracted component with prefix for responsive?

Tags: components, apply, responsive, prefix, tailwind-css

I am a beginner web designer, using windows10.

I'm using tailwind(version 1.9.6)

I want to use prefix( such as sm and md ) with component which I extracted with `@apply` in css file, as you see below.
css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
 .itemcase {
        @apply border border-gray300 text-sm font-semibold
    }
}
```

I thought the code below would work, but did not work.

```
@layer components {
 .itemcase:sm {
        @apply border border-gray300 text-lg font-bold
    }
}
```

how can I solve this problem?

I read documents( https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives ) that seemed to be related to this problem, but could not reached the solution.
Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
 .itemcase {
        @apply border border-gray-300 text-sm font-semibold
    }
}
```

Maybe it works.